# Not able to upload images on server in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services

I am trying to upload an image to a server but I am not able to upload the image to a server.
I am selecting the image from iPad library and send it to the server.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{

    SelectPickerimageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 600, 200,     200)];
    SelectPickerimageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:SelectPickerimageView];
}



-(void)method_OpenImagePickerLibrary{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}



-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    SelectPickerimageView.image=image;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(void)pushUpload{

    NSData *imgaeData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(SelectPickerimageView.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://projectsatseoxperts.net.au/fishing/api/image.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

     NSLog(@"request is:%@",request);

     NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
     NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary = %@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


     NSLog(@"request is:%@",request);


    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%\r\n",boundary]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imgaeData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];


    NSLog(@"request is:%@",request);

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"returnData: %@", returnData);

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"returnString: %@", returnString);

 }


 NSLog(@"returnString: %@", returnString);
```

Give me the response this:

You don't have permission to access the requested object.
It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

> returnString: Access forbidden! */-->

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or    not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

> Error 403
>
> projectsatseoxperts.net.au
>
> Tue Feb 4 06:09:05 2014 Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.7 mod_auth_pgsql/2.0.3

When I run the code my `NSLog(@"returnData: %@", returnData);` have the 1066 bytes.

Now I am not able to figure out what this problem is?
What I do? I contact to my web developer and He is saying everything is ok from server.
So why I get this error.

And One thing more how do I check my post data?

Like

```
/*
NSURL *url=[NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://projectsatseoxperts.net.au/fishing/api/postUpload.php"];


NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"txt_user_Id=%@ &  txt_streetnumber=%@ & txt_streetname=%@ & txt_state=%@ & txt_country=%@ & txt_suburb=%@ &  txt_postalcode=%@ & txt_latitude=%@ & txt_longitude=%@ & txt_submitupload=%@",txt_user_Id.text,txt_streetnumber.text,txt_streetname.text,txt_state.text,txt_country.text,txt_suburb.text,txt_postalcode.text, txt_latitude.text , txt_longitude.text,txt_submitupload.text];

NSLog(@"Post is: %@",post);

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSLog(@"postData is: %@",postData);

*/
```

Beacuase here I am not able to check my post data.

Any Idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: "I am uploading the image on a server but I am not able to upload the image on server." Huh?

Comment: I am trying to upload the image on server but I am not able to upload the image on server.

Comment: Try with this content type -  [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    instead of this [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible issues:

1. In the line

   ```
   NSString *contentType = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary = %@",boundary];
   ```

   you must not have spaces after `boundary` and after `=`.

   Fix:

   ```
   NSString *contentType = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
   ```

   You may enclose the boundary in double quotes.
2. In the line

   ```
   [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```

   you missed to specify a *complete* file name.
3. Possible a typo:

   ```
   -(void)ViewDidLoad
   ```